# scrolling h2 elements with scrollTo in jquery

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this scrolling problem using the scrollTo plugin for jquery.I want to be able to scroll one h2 element at a time with one click...in my script it scrolls across all h2 elements with one click..Help me please guys!!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#down').click(function(){

  $("#container h2").each(function(i,h2){
   $("#wrap").scrollTo(h2, 800, { axis:'y' });

     });
    });

 $('#up').click(function(){

      $("#container h2").reverse().each(function(i,h2){
   $("#wrap").scrollTo(h2, 800, { axis:'y' });
     });
    });
 jQuery.fn.reverse = function() {

  return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);

};
});
```

Comment: One question: If the `down` element is a the top of the page and you scroll to the first `<h2>` element and `down` is out of the view... where do you click to go further down?

Comment: the down and up elements are part of a div and are positioned each next to another.Like this:
<div id="navig">
  <a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
  <a href="#" id ="up">Up</a>
  </div>
I fixed their position with css so they don ' t move..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are calling `each()` so you perform a scroll to each `h2` per click. Keep track which element you passed scrolled to and only scroll to the next one, e.g.:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var next = 0;
     $('#down').click(function(){
        $("#wrap").scrollTo($("#container h2").eq(next), 800, { axis:'y' });
        next++;
     });
 });
```

**Update:**

You have to make sure that the counter does not increase or decrease to much. I changed it also a little to not always use the selector to find all the `h2` elements. It is sufficient to get them once. The counter check should also fix the problem when you are at the last element and click `down` (resp. when you are at the first element and click `up`):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var elements = $("#container h2");
     var next = 0;
     var max = elements.length;
     $('#down').click(function(){
        if(next+1 < max) {
            next++;
            $("#wrap").scrollTo(elements[next], 800, { axis:'y' });
        }
     });

     $('#up').click(function(){
        if(next-1 > -1) {
            next--;
            $("#wrap").scrollTo(elements[next], 800, { axis:'y' });
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot, there seems to be a problem when I reach the last h2 element, if I keep clicking the down button it goes up for a few pixels per click..strange.Can you help me maybe with the reverse part?

Comment: @Bruno: Great :) Please mark my answer as accepted then by clicking the green check mark besides it. So others also see that this question is solved.